# How do I execute a command before kickstart parses ks.cfg?

Tags: redhat, kickstart

How do I execute a command before kickstart parses ks.cfg?

My specific problem is that I want to install redhat into a tmpfs by telling kickstart:

```
part / --fstype ext3 --size 1000 --maxsize 4000 --ondisk loop1
```

I've tried doing:

```
%pre
#!/bin/sh
mkdir /tmp-root
mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp-root
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp-root/tmp-root.img bs=4096 count=1000000
losetup /dev/loop1 /tmp-root/tmp-root.img
```

but that is not done early enough. Ugh!

Update: I'm beginning to think it has nothing to do with being done early enough. I believe it has to do with anaconda and kudzu not thinking that a loopback device is a valid device. I'm not a python guy, so the idea of hacking up the kickstart code sucks!

-Vinnie

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to %include your disk config, something like this:

```
%include /tmp/part.ks

%pre 
cat > /tmp/part.ks <<END
part / --fstype ext3 --size 1000 --maxsize 4000 --ondisk loop1
END

mkdir /tmp-root
mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp-root
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp-root/tmp-root.img bs=4096 count=1000000
losetup /dev/loop1 /tmp-root/tmp-root.img
```

Comment: Hmm... that seems round about... I don't know why that is any more advantageous then hard coding the "part" line in the command section, but I'll try it when I get a chance tomorrow.

Comment: %include directives are special - anaconda parses the kickstart file once, runs all the %pre code, then parses it again to pull in the %include files